# What happens during instrument calibration?

Tags: calibration, instrumentation

I've worked with a lot of instrumentation for both non-electrical phenomena (UV-vis spectrophotometer measuring DNA concentration, MEMS gyroscopes) and electrical ones (the usual oscilloscope, multimeter, VNA, etc.). In all these cases, the lab/ company would hire a vendor tech to perform an annual calibration. I'm trying to understand a general framework for what takes place during calibration.

At a high level, there are many transduction and analog stages that translate the physical quantity being measured into the ADC output values. The relation between the quantity being measured and ADC output is some arbitrary, hopefully monotonic function. Any linearities are "fortuitous", from lots of non-linear behaviors cancelling each other out or being corrected in software, so linearity should not generally be expected.

My understanding of the callibration process:

The input-output curve between the physical quanitty of interest and the output ADC measurement will drift over time. Given all the nonlinearities any real world system will have (temperature dependence, mechanical nonlinearities, whatever else), the best we can hope for is to identify certian known inputs ("calibration points") to certain output points. Then we can make some interpolation for inputs in between those standard inputs for what the ADC outputs will be, and apply some correction in firmware/ software.

My questions are along the lines of:

- When a tech callibrates an instrument, are they physically adjusting the measurement system (realigning some light source, tightening some spring, etc.) so that the outputs for the calibration points are "correct", or are they just recording the new input-output curve?
- What model/ assumptions are made to interpolate the input-output data from calibration standards to inputs in-between the calibration points? For a high end sensor, my impression is that this is a generally non-linear physics model that incorporates the calibration point, temperature, humidity, environmental magnetic field strength, manufacturing differences between components, etc.
- Instead of making an input-output curve for the system as a whole, do calibration processes ever measure/tune the individual subcomponents of the measurement? Bad Illustrative Example: A company builds an MIMO array IC. Could they, during an annual calibration, measure the size of the chip to see how thermal cycles have shrunk or grown the IC? This value would then be a constant that's put into firmware that is one of many inputs into an arbitrary input-output function. Or maybe this is adjusted somewhere in the analog world with a potentiometer.
- The answers to the above about "what happens during a calibration", are they different at all for "user calibration" processes, e.g., putting a 50 ohm standard into a VNC?

I think what I'm getting at, is that when people say an instrument needs to be calibrated, I can't tell if there's really one process here involving linear approximated input-output curves, or it's really a catch-all word for a bunch of proceses, unique to every instrument, including physically tuning subsystems, measuring sub-components outputs (has the reference voltage IC drifted?), and updating input coefficients in for some arbitrary input-output transfer function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a) it depends on the instrument, and b) nowadays its just recording a new input/output curve for 99% of instruments (since it's all digital now), and possibly c) verifying that it isn't so far out of whack that it can't be calibrated

Comment: All of the above, depending on the instrument. I think you mean 'interpolated' when you write 'extrapolated', few engineers would risk their reputation designing an extrapolating instrument.

Comment: Spectrometers have two types of calibration. One is to calibrate the wavelength to pixel position and is done with a lamp emitting at discrete and known wavelengths and the relative sensitivity which is usually done with a black body source as the detector output has some wavelength dependence.

Comment: Thanks @Neil_UK, have corrected extrapolated to interpolated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simplified or bright-line answer to your question. You do touch on a few differences with respect to calibration -- such as whether or not there may be a continuum over a range or just a few isolated calibration points to work with.

To use temperature as an example, there is a continuum over a short range using Standard Platinum Resistance Thermometers (SPRTs). But the range is limited. There are also freeze/melt/triple points which provide a few isolated temperature points, as well. The recent [ITS-90](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=905199) provides a full description of the more recent temperature standards that reach from 0.65 Kelvin to at or above 2011 Kelvin. Feel free to skim through it to get an idea about the topic of temperature, alone.

Just so we are on the same page, calibration is about trueness (the reciprocal idea to systematic error) as it also combines with precision to make up something called accuracy. I'll borrow the following image from [this site](https://theory.labster.com/accuracy-and-precision-idk/) to help make some points clearer:

[image]

Note that a device may be very true (very low systematic error) but still may be noisy and imprecise. (Compare the two targets on the upper half of the image above.)

The term "calibration" may include steps to first improve precision before taking later steps needed to reduce systematic error. But the goal for calibration is that the instrumental *accuracy* after calibration meets or exceeds the instrument's specifications. And accuracy includes both systematic error (trueness) and precision.

Looking at the above targets, let's say that if the measurements are all on the target and none of them miss it, then it is calibrated. If so, then the only target that needs some calibration would be the lower left hand target where one of the measurements was "off the target." By adjusting the systematic error, and doing nothing at all for its precision, it should be possible to bring that instrument back into meeting its specifications for accuracy. But do note that accuracy includes the combined result of systematic error and precision.

Using the above targets again, suppose the specification is "hitting the target" (as before) and that new instruments usually show a precision that is represented by the two targets on the right. These instruments use a photodiode as their primary sensor that is exposed to nuclear radiation during use. New, let's say, the instrument shows the upper-right target behavior. But after a year, the radiation-induced degradation leads to a widening spread of measurements. So the upper-left target's behavior is the same instrument after one year's time. It's still within its specifications.

But suppose another case where its systematic error, when new and first off the shelf, wasn't quite as nicely centered. More like the lower-right target, let's say (but perhaps clustered to the left side rather than the right.) And in this case, after a year's time of use, it's spread out from there and the measurements look more like the lower-left target behavior. The precision is no worse than before, but it's no longer "in calibration." Some of the measurements are off the target, now.

A calibration procedure to repair this instrument could: (A) replace the photodiode to improve the precision and bring it back into calibration; or, (B) adjust the systematic error to pull the spread a little bit to the right, leaving the photodiode in place, degraded; or, (C) do both (and more, perhaps.)

Drift over time may and usually does affect systematic error. It also may (or may not) affect precision. Calibration is about ensuring that an instrument meets or exceeds its accuracy specifications. That's all. How exactly that is achieved differs. Not only differs between different kinds of instrumentation, but it may differ from time to time even for the exact same instrument (part replacement vs systematic error adjustment or reprogramming of a table for same.)

The target placement itself is a matter for standards organizations. The ITS-90 mentioned above is an international agreement and the result of a great deal of effort. Standards organizations, such as NIST (US) or DIN (Germany), work to establish practical standards for industry and research purposes and often provide services, too.

To calibrate a voltmeter, for example, one would either need to go visit NIST (or else send the voltmeter to NIST and ask them for a table of errors to be produced under specified conditions.) Or, alternatively, someone else can do that and you can hire them to use their newly calibrated unit to compare with yours. This last case would be a "traceable standard" and you would get paperwork from the "someone else" that certifies that they used a properly calibrated device to provide calibration information for your device. The provenances are important here. And the further away from NIST (or DIN) that you get from a direct calibration by a standards agency, the more likely unknown errors creep into the results. So I will usually ask NIST to directly provide a calibration table for me, sending the unit to them for testing, or else I will buy services from someone who did exactly that. But I won't buy 3rd tier services (yet another step removed from NIST) unless it's not important to me.

Time also matters. So a calibration service. using their own traceable standard, will also provide information on when their own equipment was last calibrated and by whom and using what equipment. Technically, you should be able to trace all the way back to an actual calibration taking place at a standards institute using your paperwork as a basis.

I don't know if any of this helps answer your actual question. But it is what resonated in me upon hearing it. Hope it helps a little.